# XSLT Format Date to MM DD YYYY

Tags: javascript, date, xslt, format

I am trying to format an XML date using XSLT/X-Path.

I have: `PostDate="2014-03-27"`
I'd like to to render as: `March 27, 2014`.

I have read that XSLT may not be the way to go. Is JavaScript a better way? Can someone please offer some assistance?

Thank you!

Robin

Comment: With XPath 3.0 (or using XSLT 2.0) you could simply use: `format-date(//date, '[MNn] [D01], [Y0001]')` to obtain what you want. But it seems that you are going to process that in a browser, which supports only XSLT 1.0. In that case, using JS might be simpler

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some XSLT and XPath solutions. If you are going to process this at the client-side (browser) you will have to stick to the XSLT 1.0 solution (or use JavaScript). If you generate your result somewhere else (standalone or server-side), you might be able to use a XSLT2/XPath3 compatible processor.

**XPath 3.0 solution**

```
format-date(//*/@PostDate, '[MNn] [D01], [Y0001]')
```

**XSLT solutions**

*Source XML*:

```
<Message PostDate="2014-03-27">Some text</Message>
```

*XSLT 2.0 stylesheet*:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
    <xsl:template match="Message">
        <date>
            <xsl:value-of select="format-date(@PostDate, '[MNn] [D01], [Y0001]')"></xsl:value-of>
        </date>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

*XSLT 1.0 stylesheet*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
    <xsl:template name="month-name">
        <xsl:param name="month"/>
        <xsl:if test="$month = 1">January</xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="$month = 2">February</xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="$month = 3">March</xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="$month = 4">April</xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="$month = 5">May</xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="$month = 6">June</xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="$month = 7">July</xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="$month = 8">August</xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="$month = 9">September</xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="$month = 10">October</xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="$month = 11">November</xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="$month = 12">December</xsl:if>    
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="format-iso-date">
        <xsl:param name="iso-date"/>
        <xsl:variable name="year" select="substring($iso-date, 1, 4)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="month" select="substring($iso-date, 6, 2)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="day" select="substring($iso-date, 9, 2)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="month-name">
            <xsl:call-template name="month-name">
                <xsl:with-param name="month" select="$month"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($month-name, ' ',$day, ', ', $year)"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Message">
        <date>
            <xsl:call-template name="format-iso-date">
                <xsl:with-param name="iso-date" select="@PostDate"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </date>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XSLT output:

```
<date>March 27, 2014</date>
```

You can also use the `date` functions in the EXSLT extension: http://www.exslt.org/

Answer (score 2):

Here is yet another method to format dates like this if you are stuck using the MSXML XSL 1.0 processor by Microsoft.  You'll need to use Javascript/JScript (or another language such as C#).

When adding in code this way, don't forget to use CDATA sections to make sure the XSL processor skips over certain symbols in the code sections.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
      xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
      xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
      xmlns:user="http://mycompany.com/mynamespace">

<msxsl:script language="jscript" implements-prefix="user"><![CDATA[
   function jsdate() 
   {
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!

    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    if(dd<10){
        dd='0'+dd
    } 
    if(mm<10){
        mm='0'+mm
    } 
    var today = dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy;

    return today; 
   }
//]]></msxsl:script>

   <xsl:template match= "/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="MySection"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="MySection">
        <IssueDate><xsl:value-of select="user:jsdate()"/></IssueDate>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```