# How do I format a date string dateServed="06/20/2014" in xsl

Tags: xslt

I have this in xml and I want to transform the document using xslt. How do I convert this dateServed string to date? `<NotificationEvent dateServed="06/20/2014"</NotificationEvent>`

**I want the result to be 2014/06/20**

Comment: Do you mean in XSLT 2.0? What do you want the result to look like?

Comment: There are several examples here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23063641/3190413

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to convert `"06/20/2014"` to a date in order to "format" it as `"2014/06/20"`. You can simply re-arrange it using string functions:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(@dateServed, 7), '/', substring(@dateServed, 1, 5))"/>
```