# Convert "15 Dec 2022" to 2022-12-15" using XSLT

Tags: xslt, date-conversion

I am trying to transform the following XML using XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <CandidateId>863</CandidateId>
   <CaseId>2762833</CaseId>
   <Status>Completed</Status>
   <InitiatedDate>01 Dec 2022</InitiatedDate>
   <CompletionDate>15 Jan 2022</CompletionDate>
   <Comments />
</root>
```

My XSLT code is as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">

<JobApplication>
<xsl:for-each select="root">
<JobApplication>

<xsl:variable name="month" select="substring(InitiatedDate,4,3)" />

<xsl:if test="$month = 'Dec'">
     <xsl:variable name="m">12</xsl:variable>
     </xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="$month = 'Nov'">
     <xsl:variable name="m">11</xsl:variable>
     </xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="$month = 'Oct'">
     <xsl:variable name="m">10</xsl:variable>
     </xsl:if>

<Bbgvdate><xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(InitiatedDate,8,4),'-',$m,'-',substring(InitiatedDate,1,2),'T00:00:00')"/></Bbgvdate>
<applicationId><xsl:value-of select="CandidateID"/></applicationId>

</JobApplication>
</xsl:for-each>
</JobApplication> 

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now, I am unable to call the variable "m" for some reason in "Bbgvdate"
I am looking for a converted date that looks like "2022-12-15" (in yyyy-mm-dd format)

I get the error:
Unable to generate the XML document using the provided XML/XSL input. Errors were reported during stylesheet compilation

Need help with this.

Thanks

Comment: A variable defined inside `xsl:if` has no scope outside it. Define your variable first, then place `xsl:choose` (not multiple `xsl:if`s) inside it - see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55101457/3016153